# Putty: limit to where you send your keys

Tags: ssh, putty

with putty agent on windows, how can i limit to which hosts i even send my keys auth tries?

mostly concerned with applications that uses plink connecting to hosts i don't know about.

does pagent have that kind of control?

Answer (score 3):

You can configure this not per host, but per connection profile.

Under *Connection → Auth*, specify the key file you need. PuTTY will still use the agent, but will only offer the matching key.

Comment: i use my keys almost exclusively with other things than putty itself. mostly via plink to authenticate on git and mercurial clients. with the occasional scp. sorry the question was too brief. will expand it when I'm out of the mobile

Comment: Well, plink also supports PuTTY's stored sessions.

Comment: hum. ok, so never add the keys to pagent/plink? add all the hosts i plan to ever connect with it's own key info, and let pagent/plink figure out from the saved sessions? will try that as soon as i'm back on windows monday and report back!